# Include information about the value's type in "keyof" type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'd like to make the following code work (dummy code to highlight my problem):

```
function setPropertyToEmptyString<T>(record: T, propertyKey: keyof T) {
  record[propertyKey] = '';
}
```

This code fails to compile with the following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
  'T[keyof T]' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

Is there a way to indicate that the propertyKey is a keyof T that points to a string property, if possible without adding a new Type parameter to the function?

Comment: Does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/WJp6vN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer (unless I find a suitable dupe target). If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ideally, I was imagining a solution where I wouldn't need to change the type parameter T of the method, where only the type of the "propertyKey" param would be changed.

Comment: There may be a way for me to make it work though, by typing the record as T and Record<K, string> at the cost of an additional type param.

If there's no miracle solution involving only the typing of the key, I'll take it :)

Comment: There's no magical solution in the absence of [ms/TS#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992); you could try to emulate it like  [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO1qRm) but the compiler doesn't "get" it and you need type assertions.  I don't understand why you need to keep `T` in there; could you [edit] to motivate that instead of just saying it isn't what you imagined doing? Like, *why* can't we replace T with K? Is there some use case that breaks? If so, please show it.   How would you like me to proceed?

Comment: You've given me the answers I need. I though a "magical" keyof T: string syntax could have existed but the ticket you linked proves otherwise. In the absence of such syntax, the solution you linked in your first comment is a good option that I think I can make work in my actual code (it's just that the magical solution would have implied less code changes if it existed).

If you want to give an official answer to this post indicating that the magical solution does not exist and showing the fallback, I'll validate it.

Comment:  I'll write it up when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported way to do this is to refactor so your function is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of `propertyKey` instead of the type of `record`:

```
function setPropertyToEmptyString<K extends PropertyKey>(
    record: Record<K, string>,
    propertyKey: K
) {
    record[propertyKey] = ''; // okay
}
```

That works because the type `Record<K, string>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)) is known to have `string` property values at keys of type `K`, and therefore you're allowed to write such properties with no error.

---

There is currently no great solution that leaves the function generic only in the type `T` of `record`.

There's no built-in type operator `KeysMatching<T, V>` to get just the keys of a type `T` whose values are compatible with a type `V`, such that the compiler would understand that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>]` is assignable to `V` even if `T` and `V` are generic.  That means even if you write a custom utility type to compute it, the compiler won't "get" it inside your generic function.  There's a feature request [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) asks for such an operator, but for now it's not part of the language.

You can make a custom utility type that does this, as follows:

```
type KeysMatchingForWriting<T, V> =
    keyof { [K in keyof T as [V] extends [T[K]] ? K : never]: any }
```

using [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to suppress any keys that are not appropriate.  Note that this returns the keys of `T` whose properties can will let you *write* a `string` to them, not those that will let you *read* a `string` from them.  They are distinct: imagine the type

```
interface Foo {
    a: "abc",
    b: string,
    c: unknown
}
```

You can *read* a `string` from the `a` and `b` properties, and you can *write* a `string` to the `b` and `c` properties.  If you try to write a `string` to `a` or read a `string` from `c` you run the risk of doing something incorrect.

Anyway you can write that custom utility type, but the compiler doesn't "get" it inside the function implementation, so you'd need all kinds of [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to get it to compile:

```
function setPropertyToEmptyString<T>(record: T, propertyKey: KeysMatchingForWriting<T, string>) {
    (record as Record<string, string>)[propertyKey as string] = '';
}
```

That might be acceptable if you care mostly about *callers* passing in non-generic inputs:

```
const f: Foo = { a: "abc", b: "def", c: 123 };
setPropertyToEmptyString(f, "b"); // okay
setPropertyToEmptyString(f, "c"); // okay
setPropertyToEmptyString(f, "a"); // error! 
// Argument of type '"a"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"b" | "c"'
```

But making the function generic in `K` and not `T` is easier to write and support.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBxCwICcCW8CSwACpgPYxYAuAngNIRVIDeAsAFBIdIBmArsPBWwlgSKBArEylKgBUSAUTAxqAZQo5gAcwA8NJBAAeFdABMoSSeUzU6VAHwAKNpxdJMEeCUwmAXEgBKHl4mugA0ourYWnahzq4cMKRWNvR+NHEcAJRMGa7unt4A2olS1rT0ALpIALxIAOR1ANy5AL5sbaxsoJCwCMhoGDj4wIEFJjmd7JzU5Ei2UACyIBTwABZRmgBiXgDqOIJa2jLhAGp2NbkuANb0JFxMSIV6UUg3VHdIMkggUIUnVYZjMAzI8ZE8KlUAPxzJB+DAANywFT8IGADA6uV4-EEwlE4ks0jkimUVDUGh0Mkc+WCfmOSBKyXKVDS9EWyzWG22mD22AOFPCUEi0WyLCm8Qc1O833Mo2C2kF5IFQs0dkyxSS0ls0oi5KqtQazTFSAxRqixkwXD6SG2JAm8Q4ID8ACIQAAjeBO2JGlyuvwKjZe+1IeB+PhXYAkADuwFabFynmAgu4fhtNQejqQLvdnqQvszJggXBzIaQAEYAEwAZmNhpcYgkGrKRKUqmVDi44SdrqdmUaSAA9P2kCQriAqLl6wSmwoW6S2x3Mx7ewOhyOxxP8Y3qM2SWSNu3OyAe33B-pMKRMABCJC5U8AQUwmh4kGAFGH9xmyDqLqddSQ2HMCM3x+KBsE0UBXQAG2QChbTgTBwHELB3yQT96i7J0kAAH0XX8ADoHCrAAWABWTI40mFogA)